# SQL query with various BETWEEN clauses

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table of companies. (ID,name,...,multiple IP-ranges)

Each company has some IP-ranges (different count of IP-ranges)

some companies may have only two IP-ranges, say 1.1.1.1-2.2.2.2 , 3.3.3.3-4.4.4.4

other companies may have more IP-ranges.(1.1.1.1-2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3-4.4.4.4,5.5.5.5-6.6.6.6 ...)

I have considered another table for IP-ranges. (one-to-many relation).

The problem is, an arbitrary IP is given, and I should find companies, which given IP belongs to their IP-range.

How can I do that?

If we have only for example two IP-ranges (from_1,to_1,from_2,to_2,  we can write `WHERE (x BETWEEN from_1 AND to_1) OR (x BETWEEN from_2 AND to_2)`.   But we have VARIANT IP-ranges. some companies may have 3 or 4 IP-ranges. One way is to create 20 columns for 10 IP-ranges . from_1,to_1, from_2,to_2,from_3,to_3 ... Is there any other way? What if some company has more than 10 IP-Ranges?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think unions can help. but I think it would be very slow. Idon't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical IP is A.B.C.D with each A, B, C, D is a 1 byte int number having value from 0 to 255, therefore you can consider an IP as a four-digit number with base of 256. Let's convert it to integer:

```
A*255^3 + B*255^2 + C*255 + D
```

Save int values of IP range into db (2 columns, FROM and TO), example with range of 1.1.1.1 - 2.2.2.2, you save:

```
FROM = 1*255^3 + 1*255^2 + 1*255 + 1 = 16646656 

TO = 2*255^3 + 2*255^2 + 2*255 + 1 = 33293312
```

Now with give IP, also convert it to integer like above (suppose the int value is x), and query:

```
SELECT Name FROM IP INNER JOIN COMPANY ON IP.CompanyId = COMPANY.Id
WHERE x BETWEEN `FROM` AND `TO`
```

**Example:**

***Company*** table

```
--------------------
| Id | Name        |
--------------------
| 1  | Google      |
--------------------
| 2  | Microsoft   |
--------------------
```

***IP*** table

```
----------------------------------------
| Id | CompanyId | From     | To       |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | 16646656 | 33293312 |
----------------------------------------
| 2  | 1         | 11235468 | 15612545 |
```

For example, the given IP is 17654343,

```
  SELECT * FROM IP INNER JOIN COMPANY ON IP.CompanyId = COMPANY.Id
  WHERE 17654343 BETWEEN `FROM` AND `TO`
```

The result:

```
Google
```

Comment: Thanks. yes. I will save IPs as integers. The problem is,for each record we have various counts of  WHERE x BETWEEN `FROM` AND `TO`

Comment: I don't understand "have various counts of WHERE ", pls update on your question.

Comment: some companies may have only two IP-ranges, say 1.1.1.1-2.2.2.2 , 3.3.3.3-4.4.4.4

other companies may have more IP-ranges.(1.1.1.1-2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3-4.4.4.4,5.5.5.5-6.6.6.6 ...) how can we write a single query ?

Comment: Can, the `FROM` and `TO` is columns name, only one input is 'x'. Maybe you missunderstand `FROM` and `TO` is input variables?

Comment: If we have only for example two IP-ranges (from_1,to_1,from_2,to_2,  we can write `WHERE (x BETWEEN from_1 AND to_1) OR (x BETWEEN from_2 AND to_2)`.   But we have VARIANT IP-ranges. some companies may have 3 or 4 IP-ranges. One way is to create 20 columns for 10 IP-ranges . from_1,to_1, from_2,to_2,from_3,to_3 ... Is there any other way? What if some company has more than 10 IP-Ranges?

Comment: I explain in my answer, if you still cannot understand, I cannot explain more clear :D